# Keycloak administration console not working

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keycloak

For me Keycloak is working but when I click on Administration console it showing error 404 Not found.

Keycloak url:

[image: Keycloak url]

Administration console error:

[image: Administration console error]

Comment: Have you any logs to show readers? Please obtain them and add them to your question.

Comment: I've added some tags `jboss` and `wildfly` to show this to people who might be able to debug.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Do you have a proxy in front of Keycloak (i.e. Apache HTTPD, Nginx, etc.)?  Have you tried with an incognito/private window?